# Org-mode backend: access properties in heading

Tags: org-mode

I currently begin to write a org-mode backend for a custom file format, so I can export from org-file to that format.

Therefore I need to apply properties (or attributes) to headings. My prolbem is now, how I could solve this.

I currently have the following headline function:

```
(defun org-mine-headline (headline contents info)
  (let ((full-text
         (substring-no-properties
          (org-export-data (org-element-property :title headline) info)))
        (p (org-element-property nil headline))
        (a (org-export-read-attribute :attr_mine headline)))
    (format "%s: [%s] %s" full-text p contents)))
```

Which gives me with the following org file:

```
* H1
#+PROPERTY: findme a
foo
```

the following output:

```
H1: [nil] foo
```

But I would like it to become something like that:

```
H1: [(:findme "a")] foo
```

I also tried attributes with no success:

```
* H1
#+ATTR_MINE: :findme a
foo
```

Comment: You could try `(let* ((first-keyword (car (org-element-map headline 'keyword #'identity)))
       (key (org-element-property :key first-keyword))
       (value (org-element-property :value first-keyword)))
  (list key value))`. Depends on the parse depth of `headline` whether this works or not. `key` should be `"PROPERTY"` and `value` should be `"findme a"`.

Comment: Thanks, great. That goes into the right direction, it works for the first proprerty. However, I would like to have more than one.

Comment: No problem. `org-element-map` gives you the list and you can replace  `#'identity` with the mapping from key to value. So you get the list of values.

Comment: I now going to do something like `(let* ((keywords (org-element-map headline 'keyword #'identity))
                   (values (mapcar (lambda (keyword) (org-element-property :value keyword)) keywords)))
              values)`. Not yet well formed but I think I can work it out. Thanks again for the neat trick with `org-element-map`. One question, may I need those `PROPERTY` keys?

Comment: I've added an answer where the statement from the comment is realized, i.e., `#'identity` is replaced by the map from the keys to the values. That has the advantage of a selective listing. In our example only  `PROPERTY` keys are listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `org-element-map` to convert the properties in the section following the heading into a string of values.

There follows an example which should run in the scratch buffer.
I have commented out some lines of your code to make this example independent from the org exporter.

```el
(require 'org-element)

(defun org-mine-headline (headline contents info)
  (let ((full-text
         (substring-no-properties
          ;;(org-export-data (org-element-property :title headline) info))
      "\nfull-text\n"))
    (vals (org-element-map headline 'keyword (lambda (key)
                           (when (string= (org-element-property :key key) "PROPERTY")
                             (org-element-property :value key)))))
    ;;(p (org-element-property nil headline))
    ;;(a (org-export-read-attribute :attr_mine headline))
    )
    (format "%s: [%s] %s" full-text (mapconcat #'identity vals ",") contents)))

;; test:

(let ((headline '(headline (:raw-value nil) (section (:begin 436 :end 1516 :contents-begin 436 :contents-end 1516 :post-blank 0 :post-affiliated 436 :parent nil) (keyword (:key "PROPERTY" :value "findme a" :begin 436 :end 459 :post-blank 0 :post-affiliated 436 :parent nil)) (keyword (:key "PROPERTY" :value "findother b" :begin 459 :end 486 :post-blank 1 :post-affiliated 459 :parent nil))))))
  (org-mine-headline headline " contents " nil))
```

Comment: I had to change the when condition to `(when (and (string= (org-element-property :key key) "PROPERTY")
                                   (eq (org-element-property :parent (org-element-property :parent key)) headline))`, so I don't get properties of subheadings. That now works, hoverer, I'am a bit confused. Following http://orgmode.org/manual/Property-syntax.html#Property-syntax a property has the form `#+PROPERTY: var  foo=1` and I should be able to extend the value via `#+PROPERTY: var+ bar=2`. But I get two distinct elements.

Comment: Do I have to parse them manually or is there some sort of convenience functions for that?

Comment: One more question regarding this: is it possible to have values calculated, e.g. with emacs lisp? Inline source blocks seem not to work

Comment: @Tobias Is there a builtin function for getting the headline at point? Your example seems to suggest so